# find the possible values of z

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

> given two complex number $z,w$ such number that $|z|\le1,|w|\le1$ and $|z+iw|=|z-i\overline{w}|=2$, then find the possible values of $z$

i tryed to use triangular inequality and got that

$$|z+iw|\le|z|+|iw|=|z|+|i||w|=|z|+|w|\\
|z-i\overline{w}|\le|z|+|-i\overline{w}|=|z|+|-i||\overline{w}|=|z|+|w|$$
since $|z|\le1,|w|\le1$ then
$$|z+iw|\le|z|+|w|\le2\\
|z-i\overline{w}|\le|z|+|w|\le2$$

then since $|z+iw|=|z-i\overline{w}|=2$ then $|z|+|w|=2$ and $|z|=|w|=1$ because if $|z|<1$ then $|w|>1$ and if $|w|<1$ then $|z|>1$.

Comment: Let $y=iw$. The conditions can be restated as $|z|\leq 1$, $|y|\leq 1$, $|z+y|=2$. The equality holds if and only if $z=y$ and $|z|=1$. Therefore, $z$ can be any complex number with absolute value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the hint in the coment i find that the equality holds for
$$|z+iw|\rightarrow z=iw\\
|z-i\overline{w}|\rightarrow z=-i\overline{w}$$
then
$$iw=-i\overline{w}\\
w^2=-|w|^2=-1\\
w=\pm i\\
z=iw=\pm i^2=\mp 1$$